# Insert all datagridview data into table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

This one does not add these data into the table

```
string StrQuery;
        try
        {
             SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(conString);

             SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();

                    comm.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO ItemPurchased VALUES ('" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["InvNo"].Value + "',' " + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["itemCode"].Value + "','" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity"].Value + "', '" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["itemPrice"].Value + "', '" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["itemDescription"].Value + "');";
                        comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }


        }
        catch { }
```

Comment: Maybe it's throwing an exception.  But you wouldn't know because there is nothing in the `catch {}` to alert you.

Comment: For the sake of your sql server please stop this immediately. What you have there is a textbook definition of sql injection. You need to parameterize that query and protect yourself.

Comment: I really wish .NET would disallow an empty catch. That is not error handling, it is error suppression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check the name off the variable connection, you used conn1 on declaration statment and before than, you use conn for set the connection property of command obejct.

Maybe you can improve your code creating a stored procedure on SQLServer and using that to prevent sqlinjection of your code.

Something Like this

Procedure to create assuming that your table has the same columns names as your gridview:

```
create procedure usp_itempurchased_ins

@InvNo              int,
@itemCode           int,
@Quantity           int,
@itemPrice          decimal,
@itemDescription    varchar(100)
as
begin

    insert ItemPurchased (InvNo, itemCode, Quantity, itemPrice, itemDescription)
    values (@InvNo, @itemCode, @Quantity, @itemPrice, @itemDescription)
end
```

Code on C#

```
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        try
        {


            string connString = string.Format("Password={0};User ID={1};Initial Catalog={2};Data Source={3}", "pasword", "username", "databasename", "servername");
            conn = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = connString };

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "usp_itempurchased_ins";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvNo", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["InvNo"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemCode", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["itemCode"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemPrice", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["itemPrice"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemDescription", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["itemDescription"].Value);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception exInsert)
        {
            conn.Dispose();
            LogEventViewer(string.Format("Execution problems on stored procedure usp_itempurchased_ins. {0} Mesage: {1}", Environment.NewLine, exInsert.Message));

        }

        private void LogEventViewer(string msg)
        {
            EventLog XYZeventLog = new EventLog();

            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("XYZ-LOG"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("XYZ-LOG", "XYZLOG");
            }

            XYZeventLog.Source = "XYZ-LOG";
            XYZeventLog.Log = "XYZLOG";

            using (XYZeventLog)
            {
                XYZeventLog.WriteEntry(msg, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
```

Try this and tell me if works

Best Reggards